# Google javascript map not displaying itself on android orientation landscape

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps-api-3

I am an android developer and using google javascript api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=tr for map apps.However I have faced a strange problem and unable to solve it.The problem is I cannot see map on landscape( by means of landscape is not rotating device , I am using different layouts for tablet and phone app and activities are also different and orientation locked 
       `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"` ) when I run my application on portraid mode , everthing is ok , but when I run landscape map does not displays.
My testing device is Sony Tablet S , android 4.0.3
here is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' > 
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript" src='CommunicatorClass.js' ></script>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript" src='map.js' ></script>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; width:100%;">
<div id='map-canvas' style="height:250px; width:400px; background-color:#00ff00;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and map initilize invoked by using

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window , 'load' , onPageLoaded );
```

and map loaded into webview as

```
mWebView.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/map/Map.html");
```

Comment: Why don't you use the Google Maps Android API v2? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ just wondering

Comment: I forgot to mention that , there is no error in the application and I know that map is there , becaus I can display map , and markers added to map by using javascript alert function.

Comment: Amourreux because we are working multi platform  , this map works on both ios , win8 , android and blackberry.

Comment: can you post full class?

Comment: Sorry but this is not possible since the class is very complex and contains many other codes.By the way I have tested app on another tablet (android 3.2) and it works fine.It is very weird that not working on another tablet.